# Is there any way to clone a repository from the web incrementally?

Tags: mercurial, clone

I'm on dialup in lousy place (yes, it still happens in 2011), and trying to clone a huge repository. It starts without problem, but every time the dialup disconnects (which is unavoidable, it seems), the !#%$* hg rolls everything back and I'm left again with an empty directory.

Is there a solution other than doing it on a remote PC and then downloading the whole thing by FTP or something?

Comment: It depends on the kind of access you have to the repo, but in some cases `rsync` would be an option.

Comment: `rsync` is definitely the way to go here. You will get a minimum of redundant file transmissions and guaranteed results, regardless of the number of restarts.

Answer (score 8):

In a bash-like shell you could do something like this:

```
$ hg init myclone
$ cd myclone
$ for REV in `seq 10 10 100` ; do hg pull -r $REV <REMOTEREPO>; done
```

Starting at 10, each pull downloads the next 10 revisions, up to 100. In case of a lost connection, adjust the first argument to `seq` to match what you've already pulled.

Comment: Or on the Windows command prompt: `FOR /L %A IN (10,10,100) do hg pull -r %A <REMOTEREPO>`

Comment: Although you need to be aware that the changeset numbering may be different from the upstream repository if you do it this way.

Comment: I tried pushing it further and currently maintaining a (new) repo  in case multiple of us has same problem: Please try contributing? :D https://github.com/nootanghimire/hg-clone-bash

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how flaky your connection is, there are two options for performing initial clones.

First, you can try so-called “streaming clones”. These minimize *Time To First Byte*, but do generally require a bit more data to be transferred.

Here’s how to do a streaming clone:

```
$ hg clone --uncompressed https://~~~~
```

Your second option will be a hg clone –-rev operation, followed by a number of incremental pulls. This behaves similarly to cloning a repository in some distant past and doing occasional updates.

```
$ hg clone --rev 5 https://~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions here,

I created a repo that did this.

```
https://github.com/nootanghimire/hg-clone-bash
```

It's optimized for a single repo, but i guess you can fork and work on it! :)