# How to pause/resume repository cloning in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I've recently needed to clone into development tree of some large projects (e.g. https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central), but the problem is I'm on an slow unstable connection and thus I may not clone into the repository in a single pass.

Is it possible to pause/resume the cloning process somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To clone a large repository in multiple passes, you can use the `--rev` option on the [clone command](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/clone). For example:

```
hg clone --rev 100 <remote URL> <local path>
cd <local path>
hg pull --rev 200
hg pull --rev 300
etc
```

See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716200/mercurial-hg-is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-repository-from-the-web-incrementally).

Comment: Very helpful! Please note that the very final step should be an "hg update", in order to get the pulled tip into your working directory.