# Hg clone: IIS server download limit

Tags: iis, mercurial

I'm cloning a large mercurial repository ( > 10Gb) over http protocol from an IIS 8.5 Server. Although setting the `maxAllowedContentLength` and `maxRequestLength` to values over 2Gb, I'm still unable to clone the repo. It seems I'm hitting a download limitation size. The following exception is thrown:

> bundle2-input-part: total payload size 64680856
>   bundle2-input-bundle: 0 parts total
>   transaction abort!
>   rollback completed
>   Abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 0 bytes, expected 4)

My web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
<system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="240" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="14400" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
```

To my understanding adjusting the `maxAllowedContentLength` or `maxRequestLength` to values over 2Gb does not help because these settings are for ASP.NET, and not for IIS.

Answer (score 0):

> With incremental pulls you can get the entire repository on a changeset-by-changeset basis, thus reducing the amount of data transferred during each operation to an absolute minimum:

https://www.google.com/search?q=hg+incremental+clone

particularly check out this other question
[Is there any way to clone a repository from the web incrementally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716200/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-repository-from-the-web-incrementally)

or perhaps more end-user solutions like this one https://github.com/tusharvjoshi/incremental-hg (which I don't endorse because I don't know it at all)

Comment: Not an option. We're dealing with 400.000 changesets. We did a few incremental pulls of 10.000 changesets, but again sometimes hitting the limit. I'll edit my question later today with the things we tried before. But to be short, this is an IIS problem, not a Mercurial one.